# How to Stop unnecessary empty containers [looping] in Angular accordion

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular6, accordion

How to Stop unnecessary looping in Angular accordion, Please Look into view only 3 is limit to display data and its coming correctly, but after that its creating unnecessary looping for empty panels also. please check screen shots

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the limiting items to less than 3 is getting applied to the elements inside your header div.So the header div still gets created for all the elements in the array. You can solve this in two ways

Use `ng-container` to create a wrapper element for your header div. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
    <li *ngIf="i<3">{{item}}</li>
  </ng-container>
```

Use slice pipe. https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items|slice:0:3">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Sample stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvkvmj